# How do I display the latest Unicode characters (esp. emoji) in Windows browsers?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, unicode

None of my browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE) display characters for Unicode [7](http://emojipedia.org/unicode-7.0/), [8](http://emojipedia.org/unicode-8.0/), [9](http://emojipedia.org/unicode-9.0/) (or [10](http://emojipedia.org/unicode-10.0/)) emojis:

> [image: Unicode 9 are displayed as plain boxes]

These are often sent to me by people on phones.  Unicode 6 characters are supported, but hard to read/differentiate:

> [image: Unicode 6 emojis are displayed]

How do I add support for these characters to a Windows 7 system?  Is there a way to display them the way Android does, so they are easier to read?

Test characters:

- Unicode 6.1:
- Unicode 7.0:
- Unicode 8.0:
- Unicode 9.0:
- Unicode 10.0:
- Unicode 11.0:
- Unicode 12.0:
- Unicode 13.0: …
- Unicode 14.0: …
- Unicode 15.0:

Comment: You will need a font that has these characters. Each character has a number (code point), the number is looked up in a font, and displayed.

Comment: @richard Know of any?  A browser extension that replaces them with images would also work.

Comment: what kind of websites use unicode emojies? I thought most forums use images with some markup language.

Comment: @jiggunjer Google Voice / any social site that people can post comments to from their iPhones.  Some sites replace them with graphics, like Gmail, but others do not.

Comment: You need to find out how to install a fall-back font, for your operating system / windowing system / browser. And then install a font that supports these characters. (A fall-back font is one that is used when the selected fonts do not have a glyph for the code point.)

Comment: Somehow, only the Unicode 10 ones show up. https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/ExO0_ZHZ9ADTs8FMeiRRim0Y0Ta5-gprAAEhMMoWV3JhB7HmewwfsUIrSGQV1uToNtJMbwPSNNicCP45qdtBrs4h4DoPFaRQzplmYlPwAjS4LOZqYDUydxRECiPPO31HEsVtdIbRue0

Comment: I got a new laptop with Windows 10 and it shows native emojis in Waterfox, Chrome, and Edge.

Answer (score 17):

I found [the Emoji One font](https://github.com/eosrei/emojione-color-font), which supports all the emojis up to the current Unicode version, including color emojis (by embedding SVGs or something).

If the font is specified, Firefox supports the colored emojis fine:

> [image: using the font with span tag]

and Chrome and IE support its monochrome fallbacks:

> [image: Chrome with monochrome emoji with span tag]

but just installing the `EmojiOneColor-SVGinOT.ttf` font into Windows is not good enough to get rid of the boxes, [apparently because other fonts are preferred over it](https://github.com/eosrei/emojione-color-font#install-on-windows)?

Partial workarounds:

### Chrome

Installing the [Emoji Keyboard (2016)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/emoji-keyboard-2016-by-em/ipdjnhgkpapgippgcgkfcbpdpcgifncb?authuser=8) extension and enabling "Auto-Replace" in the options (which is on by default):

> [image: Auto-Replace: Replace all emoji in Chrome to Emoji One]

produces colored emoji in Chrome up to Unicode 9.  (The supported Unicode version is stated on the [eosrei/emojione-color-font Releases](https://github.com/eosrei/emojione-color-font/releases/) page):

> [image: Colored emoji in Chrome]

The auto-replace works on every site, but not in editable text boxes.

### Firefox

Firefox displays the characters with Arial regardless of what you have installed, which you can see by installing the [FontFinder extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/font-finder/).

[A Greasemonkey script](https://gist.github.com/mienaikage/4f487dcee7d04ba2f6d4c615812af668) will add the font to the body tag of all pages, but this doesn't fix the problem on several that I tested.  It works on a few, like superuser.com.

Changing the browser's default font to Emoji One does seem to work in most cases, but may have side effects.  (For instance, this replaces the ™ sign, too, which Chrome's extension does not do.)

The [Emoji Everywhere extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/emoji-everywhere/?src=search) kind of works, but seems to slow down page load compared to the font, and only supports Unicode 6.1.

Comment: You will need to set the emoji font as a fall-back font. So it is used if all else fails. I do not know how or if you can do this on Microsoft's Windows.

Comment: There is a Windows installer now for the EmojiOne Color font v1.3+ which merge with existing fonts so all characters work.

Comment: This makes symbols from up to Unicode 9.0 just fine, but is there a way to also display proposed Unicode 10.0 symbols? E.g.: 

Comment: In case any fellow peruser is confused, like me-- the emojis in the answer above are all images : S

Comment: It looks like native emoji were added in Firefox 50?

Comment: This font seems to be known out of the box in Google Chrome on Windows : just add a fallback font in css (the last of the font-familly list). For exemple : font-familly: arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif,"EmojiOne Color"; Works like a charm !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, endolith, I was searching for this information. You really created a fine summary on the problem with Windows / Firefox and Unicode Emojis in versions higher than 6.0.

I was also looking for a possibility to upgrade Firefox on Windows 7 to show newer Emojis.

Although you tested with the Font Finder extension to find that FF uses the Arial font for displaying the Emojis the GitHub site states that Windows 7, 8 and 10 are using Segoe UI for the Emojis.

They only modify Segoe UI Symbol and Segoe UI Emoji with their new script to install Unicode V9 emojis, not the Arial font.

> Windows 7, 8, 10 use emoji from both Segoe UI Symbol and Segoe UI Emoji. We need to replace both fonts, but keep the existing symbol characters from Segoe UI Symbol.

I will test their script now although it needs additional software to work.

> This package contains an install script that will generate both fonts (or in Windows 7, just Segoe UI Symbol) and install them for you. Running the install script requires both Python and pip in the PATH.

GitHub reference: https://github.com/eosrei/emojione-color-font