# Unicode Private Use FireFox

Tags: firefox, unicode

I got this in my browser (FF), any idea about what this is?

It just did a search by itself on google

[unicode %EE%80%80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLoQK.png)

UPDATE
[google search screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eubw9.png)

Comment: What do you mean by got it in your browser? It sounds like an emoji is unable to be displayed https://superuser.com/questions/1094188/how-do-i-display-the-latest-unicode-characters-esp-emoji-in-windows-browsers

Comment: I opened my browser and by itself it just did a search on google (attached the screenshot search) and it says Private Area. To me it looks like a Javascript code hit a private area (probably google itself)

Comment: If your browser just did a search by itself then I suggest you do a malware scan. Where is it saying Private Area?

Comment: Check the first screenshot I sent. I looked for the unicode and it says its for Private Use, First, so I am guessing it hit a block that was reserved for the browser and probably it was just a start point that was called at boot. I will do as you suggest a Malware Scan. Thanks for the suggestion.  If someone has any other idea, please let me know Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Unicode, a Private Use Area (PUA) is a range of code points that, by definition, will not be assigned characters by the Unicode Consortium.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas

That's just a range of unicode. You haven't hit some private area of Google. If your browser is searching things on its own though, I would suggest scanning for malware and making sure your system is secure.